# How to execute TensorFlow serving example mnist_export without using bazel?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-serving

I've installed all the pre-requisites for TensorFlow serving as [explained here](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/setup#prerequisites)

When I tried to run default mnist example with the following line in my Ubuntu 16.04 machine:

```
python  mnist_export.py --training_iteration=1000 --export_version=1 export_models
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mnist_export.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow_serving.example import mnist_input_data
ImportError: No module named tensorflow_serving.example
```

That code is [available here](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_export.py).

However when I use bazel to build as follows, it works perfectly:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_export --training_iteration=1000 --export_version=1 export_models
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was solved by changing the following line from:

```
from tensorflow_serving.example import mnist_input_data
```

to this line:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets import mnist as mnist_input_data
```

This problem is [discussed here](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/52).